# Cisco call manager - сколько звонков дозвона можно поставить?

Tags: cisco, телефония

Свалилась на меня эта штука и не могу понять, почему после двух звонков снаружи на наши номера происходит "отбой" после двух трелей. Не все успевают схватить трубку за два сигнала. А найти в настройках не успеваю - там их тонна.

Просьба подсказать, кто знает.

Comment: какой еще автоответчик и зачем на него капать?

Comment: вдруг аппарат пытается передать какие либо инструкции автоответчику (или ещё кому), а адресата либо не существует чтобы принять обработку, либо он (адресат) выполняет инструкции неверно. Другими словами с самим Cisco call manager может быть всё впорядке

Comment: Вопрос был - "сколько звонков дозвона можно поставить?" и где эти настройки. Я не спрашивал что-то другое так что спасибо не надо фантазий на простой вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте капнуть в сторону автоответчика, или чего то что должно включаться автоматически, может факс на проводе висит.